# Writing variable value into a file as a table

Tags: excel, matlab, file

Can anyone please explain to me, is there a way I could write values into a file, but like a matrix, so that I can use that file in excel or Matlab. I save current output of the variable as:

```
 ofstream myfile;
 myfile.open ("force.txt", ios::app);
 myfile << force;
 myfile << ";";
 myfile.close();
```

Output is:

```
'7.57549;7.55057;7.55429;7.53685;7.54691;7.58714;7.52743;7.54996;7.54721;7.53529;7.5554;7.54338;7.54377;7.55719;7.5804;7.54457;7.53157;7.59842;7.60967;7.63046;7.58049;7.5497;7.50228;7.49834;7.52993;7.5139;7.48712;7.4576;7.4434;7.42198;7.42469;7.46488;7.44662;7.39675;7.34764;7.45949;7.40383;7.38255;7.39553;7.37388;7.38452;7.38368;7.37266;7.35141;7.30514;7.32797;7.31768;7.29029;7.30962;7.28761;7.31052;7.32694;7.37853;7.36935;7.3836;7.32644;7.29701;7.31455;7.31339;7.39288;7.38463;7.34823;7.32674;' etc.
```

I want to get it, somehow in a array or table or something like that, like `|7.39288|7.29701|` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Matlab and Excel understand the CSV (Comma-Separated Value) file format. The easiest way to write a matrix in Matlab to a `.csv` file is to use [`csvwrite`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html). To read from a `.csv` file in Matlab you can use [`csvread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html). A `.csv` file can be opened in excel like a normal excel workbook, `.xls` file.

```
>> M = rand(5);
>> csvwrite('M.csv', M);
```

Answer (score 0):

consider you have a `matrix` ( `vector` in your example) like:

```
force=[7.57549;7.55057;7.55429;7.53685;7.54691;7.58714;7.52743;7.54996;7.54721;7.53529]
```

you can use

```
dlmwrite('myFile.txt', force);
```

to save your matrix as a txt file.